# How do I implement training data for Supervised Learning if my target answers are located in the rows instead of columns?

Tags: python, machine-learning

**Context:**
The machine learning that I am currently doing is to classify a line graph.
The picture in the link roughly how the data set look like. All the **x values** represent the **x coordinates** which is the same for all target answers. The only differences are the **y values** which represents the **y coordinates**.

[Image for how the data set look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyrIl.png)

[Image for Actual Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka3N3.png)

[What I am suppose to predict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYjK8.png)    << I am suppose to predict what unknown is

**Problem:** I am only used to target answers being in the column instead of the row. I tried transposing the whole entire excel but unfortunately, the datasheet is too large(too many indices in the array)

**Question:** How do I go about preparing the datasheet to train the machine?

Comment: welcome! To see if I get you right, you mean the "label" is tuple (Targe1, Target2, ..., Target40)? I don't understand what you are trying to predict. Every row should have one classification, which is the label. what information is the label in your dataset?

Comment: All target answers seem to be the same for all x coordinates. This is always the case? Request you to rephrase the question some more. It isn't clear- what you have, what you'd like etc.

Comment: Hi thanks for the replies! Sorry for poor structure in the question, I have added some more image for more clarification. 
Basically, the aim of the machine is to predict the material of object. I acquired the data by using a spectrometer. Data detected by a spectrometer is normally recorded in waveform hence the x and y coordinates. 
The target label is basically, the first row of each column excluding x-axis. I know that every row should have one classification but data is given from the spectrometer itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert all target columns into one vector :). Then have X be the input to a machine learning function and Y would be the output.